# How to Recover Data from internal storage of dead phone?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, data-recovery

I'm Using a Intex Aqua Power HD phone with Android 4.4. Its broken and cannot be switched it on... Whatever be the problem with the phone, what I really want is the data in that phone... The data in the phone is important... Is there any way to recover Data from Internal Storage of my Phone When I cannot turn it on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to access the internal storage from a dead phone that I know of would be to open it and use specialized tools to connect directly to the flash memory chip, which is a complicated process. If your phone does boot but the screen stays black, then you might have a chance to connect it and access internal files using  [ADB](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-set-up-android-adb-and-fastboot-on-windows-tutorial/)

Comment: So I think it would be better to consult a specialized technician.... Thank you...